# Why do I get a warning about NSMutableArray incompatible pointer type?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I receive a simple text string on my iPad and I am trying to simply parse this into a table view, but I get the following warning:

```
"Incompatible pointer type assigning to 'NSMutableArray*' from 'NSArray'"
```

So, controller.h

```
NSMutableArray *homeData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *homeData;
```

then, controller.m

```
@synthesize homeData;
```

followed by

```
[searchData appendData:data];
NSString *searchString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:searchData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *sectionString = [searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@";;"];
homeData = [[[sectionString objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] retain];

(data = 'no_home;;no_locl;;no_natl;;9:CHardaker;;')
```

Under normal circumstances, the string will hold a list of index numbers and abbreviated names, up to 100.

I get the warning on the final homeData line. I would expect that `homeData objectAtIndex:0` should be `no_home`, however it is not and this is the only issue outstanding in the execution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`componentsSeparatedByString:` returns an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`. If you want the mutable variant, change the last line to:

```
homeData = [[[sectionString objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] mutableCopy];
```